# How to fetch the user email address from sender_id field of Mentions webhook of Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-webhooks, userinfo

I have subscribed to Page Mention webhook of Facebook Graph API. It returns me a response in this format :

```
{
    "entry": [
        {
            "id": "0",
            "time": 1690196803,
            "changes": [
                {
                    "field": "mention",
                    "value": {
                        "post_id": "44444444_444444444",
                        "sender_name": "Example Name",
                        "item": "post",
                        "sender_id": "44444444",
                        "verb": "add"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "object": "page"
}
```

I am not finding any clear documentation of how can I fetch the user's info/email-id. Is it possible to fetch the user's email address from sender_id somehow?

Comment: Only if the user previously logged into your app, and granted it permission to read their email.

Comment: Even if I have the permission. How is the sender_id related to user_id? I had read in some docs that it isnt the same. How are the two related?

Comment: It might be a page-scoped user id, but that should not stop you from accessing it with a page access token. (After prior authorization by the user.)